# 301 redirect to domain with # in the URL

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm currently attempting to redirect the below:

```
bar.com/foo ====> bar.com/bar.html#/#
```

My redirect rule is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/foo$  bar.com/bar.html#/#  [R=301,L,NC]
```

Here's the output when I run a test curl:

```
301 http://bar.com/foo ======>
https://bar.com/bar.html%23/%23
```

It's returning a 301 HTTP response; however, are these %23 characters an encoding indication that the # will be present in the URL after the redirect, or a literal representation of the URL?  Is there any escaping I need to do if this is incorrect?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NE` option to avoid encoding:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?foo/?$ /bar.html#/# [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser to avoid old cache.